# TerraClimate: Error generating chart: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, chart, string

I am using "TerraClimate: Monthly Climate and Climatic Water Balance for Global Terrestrial Surfaces, University of Idaho" dataset...

When I try my code, I have this error message `Error generating chart: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string`.

I'm interesting to vapor pressure deficit. Here is my code:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE')
.filter(ee.Filter.date('1958-01-01', '2020-12-01'))
.filterBounds(geometry);
print (dataset); 

var Vapor_pressure_deficit = dataset.select('vpd');
print (Vapor_pressure_deficit);

var VPD = Vapor_pressure_deficit.map(function(img){
var date = img.get('system:time_start');
return img.multiply(0.01).set('system_time_start', date);
});

var createTS = function(img){
var date = img.get('system_time_start');
var value = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry).get('vpd');
var ft = ee.Feature(null, {'system:time_start': date, 
                             'date': ee.Date(date).format('Y/M/d'), 
                             'value': value});
  return ft;
};
var vpd_final = VPD.map(createTS);

var graph = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(vpd_final, 'system:time_start', 'value');

print(graph.setChartType("ColumnChart")
           .setOptions({vAxis: {title: 'VPD [kPa]'},
                        hAxis: {title: 'Date'}}));
Export.table.toDrive({collection: vpd_final, selectors: 'date, value'});
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Sorry. when I try my code, I have this error message
Error generating chart: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Comment: Can someone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, I ran the code without any issues.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing this issue with only one of my polygon geometries (the smallest polygon, covering only two sentinel pixels), while all of my other larger ones work fine.
I have only been able to solve the issue by using a point geometry instead, for the one not working.
This solution is fine for my situation, but probably not for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

this will not be a comprehensive answer, I'm a beginner, but I found something that seems to trigger it, I ran the following as part of a script after previously filtering and processing landsat 5 data to find the median of NDVI for a small polygon, e.g. 3km x 3 km, and plot over time using the resultant feature collection:

var outgraph = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(L5_reduceRegion, 'date', 'medianNDVI');

print(outgraph);

by examining the feature collection L5_reduceRegion I saw that because I had specified dates for the landsat data filter for BEFORE the start of any valid scenes (ie before the LS5 mission started), the initial date in the feature collection had a null NDVI.  Ui.chart did not like this, as soon as I adjusted the begin filter date forward it plotted just fine.   I wonder if this could be part of what other users are reporting on trying to plot very small areas, if there is cloud filtering or other factors it may create null values in the feature list or at least the initial value (?).  So it seems 'null' is a string and different from a zero result for NDVI, which is the same as errors that occur in statistical analysis with many packages.